# How to limit the list comprehension from repeating when inside a loop?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

The list is below is part of a ppm file. the three numbers are Red Green Blue. the list below is part of a bigger list name num

```
num=list below  
    [..... [155, 155, 155],...[100, 100, 100]...
    [222, 222, 222]....] 

for pixels in num:
     for rgb in pixels:
          print([255 - rgb for rbg in pixels])
```

when running this code you get

```
[100, 100, 100]
[100, 100, 100]
[100, 100, 100]
[33, 33, 33]
[33, 33, 33]
[33, 33, 33]
```

how to get so it prints only one of each not three of the same.

```
[100, 100, 100]
[33, 33, 33]
```

Comment: What are the first two lists called?

Comment: More context, please. The list comprehension is only producing one list.

Comment: The homework tag is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your inner for loop

```
>>> nums = [[155, 155, 155],
...         [222, 222, 222]]

>>> for pixels in nums:
...    print([255 - rgb for rgb in pixels])

>>> [100, 100, 100]
>>> [33, 33, 33]
```

**EDIT**: To output the `print`s to a file:

```
f = open('path/to/file', 'w')
for pixels in nums:
    f.write(', '.join(str(255 - rgb) for rgb in pixels) +'\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: `f = open('path/to/file', 'w')`

Comment: still getting [222, 222, 222] on each line... how to remove them.[], the brackets..  last question

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you have a loop that you don't need:

```
for pixels in num:
     for rgb in pixels:
          print([255 - rgb for rgb in pixels])
```

should be:

```
for pixels in num:
      print([255 - rgb for rgb in pixels])
```

else you are printing the list comprehension 3 times,for each pixel, once for each element in that pixel.